# Android, What does this in Intent(this, ........) mean

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating an Intent in android SDK but i don't know when to use the "this" value as argument or something else.. Can someone explain what "this" is used for? I know it means something like the object it's currently in but i don't know what the value is used for.

tnx.

Comment: -1: Seems like a basic java understanding is missing. Perhaps you can improve the question by adding the code you are talking about, and mentioning what links you have read. e.g. have you looked at the [Intent page on Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this** is used to refer current activity in case of Intent

Answer (score 2):

`Intent` probably takes an interface as the first parameter and your object `this` has an implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

you're making an explicit intent which takes two parameters: The context implementing the class and the activity (class) to be opened by the intent for example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
```

the `this` is specifying the context implementing the class.
take a look at the documentation for intents : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context, java.lang.Class)

It will also be able to show you the difference between an implicit and explicit intent